# Does F# type inference works top-down (and left-right) only?

Tags: f#, type-inference

I still cannot figure out why F# compiler cannot infer the type in the following example (taken from the `Programming F# 3.0` book):

```
open System.IO

// type inference ok: fileInfos : string [] -> FileInfo []
let fileInfos (files : string[]) =
    Array.map (fun file -> new FileInfo(file)) files

// type inference does not work !?
let fileSizes (fileInfos : FileInfo []) =
    Array.map (fun info -> info.Length) fileInfos
```

The explanation in the book (page 62) is:

> This is because type inference processes code from left-to-right and
>   top-to-bottom, so it sees the lambda passed to Array.map before it
>   sees the type of the array elements passed. (Therefore, the type of
>   the lambda’s parameter is unknown.)

which is reasonable in this case (for `fileInfos`, type of `file` is inferred as `string` since the constructor `FileInfo` has its parameter as `string`; for `fileSizes`, there's no such information).

But I still have doubts because if the explanation is correct, then the type inference (a variant of Hindley–Milner's algorithm W) is so limited. Indeed, there's another [source](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-inference/) says:

> ... [F#] ... type inference works top-down, bottom-up, front-to-back,
>   back-to-front, middle-out, anywhere there is type information, it will
>   be used.

*Edit: thanks to all for answers, I just add below some details to explain why I still get confused.*

In the case of `fileSizes`, the compiler knows:

- `filesInfo : FileInfo []`,
- `Array.map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a [] -> 'b []`,

it can replaces `'a` by `FileInfo`, so there must be `info : FileInfo` in the lambda `fun info -> info.Length`

I can give an example where the type inference of F# shows that it's more capable than "left-to-right, top-to-bottom":

```
// type inference ok: justF : int [] -> (int -> int -> 'a) -> 'a []
let justF (nums : int []) f =
    Array.map (fun x -> f x x) nums
```

where the compiler infers correctly the type of `f : int -> int -> 'a` (obviously it cannot have such an inference if it looks only into the lambda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F#'s type inference algorithm is somewhat limited around object instance member access - it doesn't attempt to work out the type "backwards" from them, so unless enough type information is already provided, it will just stop dead in its tracks.

This is not the case with record fields, for instance (note there's no annotation even on the function argument):

```
type FileInfoRecord = { length: int }

let fileSizes fileInfos =
    Array.map (fun info -> info.length) fileInfos
```

It's a conscious design trade-off, however - I remember hearing that it could be improved, but at the cost of less reliable intellisense and more confusing error messages (i.e. it would work fine for simple cases, but when it fails, it would fail further away from the actual line that caused the problem). With the current setup, the workaround is straightforward - just put an annotation on the lambda's argument.

I suppose that that's the price to pay for running a Hindley-Milner style type inference alongside object-oriented type hierarchies with polymorphism and overloading.

Comment: many thanks, do you know any source where can I read more on the type inference with objects?. I still get confused, because the type annotation in `fileSizes (fileInfos : FileInfo [])` should be enough to infer the type of `info` in the lambda `fun info -> info.Length`

Comment: No, that's not enough, because type inference still sees `.Length` first and because it doesn't already carry information about the type of `info`, it just gives up. You can provide that information by piping fileSizes into `Array.map`, so then it's "at the left" from that point and the type of info is known.

Comment: That's nice as far as understanding the mechanism behind it goes, but the real rule of thumb solution is to just put an annotation when the compiler complains, `fun (info : FileInfo) -> info.Length`, it's not like you get points for using the least amount of annotations.

Comment: Thanks again, so if I understand correctly, the compiler does not care for the type annotation in `let fileSizes (fileInfos : FileInfo []) = ...` (because if yes, it already knows the type of `fileInfos` then `info : FileInfo` should be the ultimate choice in the lambda `fun info -> info.Length`

Comment: @TaThanhDinh: Yes, it doesn't make the connection, because while it knows the type of `fileInfos`, it has not yet seen it being passed to `Array.map` by the time it gets to `.Length`, and because `.Length` is a member call, it just gives up at that point. Whereas if you do `fileInfos |> Array.map (fun info -> ...)`, the compiler has already seen it and the type of `info` in the lambda is "pinned" to `FileInfo` due to the annotation on `fileInfos`.

Comment: This is an unfortunate aspect of F# type inference. There is no way to validly infer, in your code, that `info` has type `FileInfoRecord`. This is a complete guess made by the compiler based on the property name `length`. If there is another type with property name `length` the inference may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use left to right type inference you can change `fileSizes` using the pipe operator `|>`. Since it already knows that `fileInfos` is an array of `FileInfo` it can deduce that `info` must be a `FileInfo`:

```
// type inference now is ok
let fileSizes (fileInfos : FileInfo []) =
    fileInfos |> Array.map (fun info -> info.Length)
```

The other way it does not work because the lambda function appears before it knows what the second parameter to `Array.map` is going to be. The pipe operator, on the other hand, already establishes that whatever comes after the pipe needs to receive an array of `FileInfo`.

In the case of `fileInfos`, like you correctly stated, it knows that `file` must be a string because that is the only type that `new FileInfo(...)` accepts. Now, imagine you wanted to use one of the OO members of `info` like `ToUpper()`. That would bring back the same error, because there could be any number of types that can have a member named `ToUpper` that returns a `string`:

```
// same type inference error
let fileInfos (files : string[]) =
    Array.map (fun file -> new FileInfo(file.ToUpper())) files
```

again you can fix it by passing files first using the pipe:

```
let fileInfos (files : string[]) =
    files |> Array.map (fun file -> new FileInfo(file.ToUpper()))
```

When using record types F# looks for a type that has a member with the same name and assumes that is the type. That may not work correctly when there is more than one possibility. In that case it will pick the latest one declared or opened.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I still get confused because in both cases, the compiler knows already `fileInfos : FileInfo []` from the type annotation.